# PHPStorm не включается

Tags: phpstorm

На днях наводил порядки на ноуте.
Сегодня пытаясь включить phpstorm столкнулся с тем, что он не включается. Попробовал открыть через консоль (PowerShell). Мне в консоли пишет следующее

phpstorm64.exe : Имя "phpstorm64.exe" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой програм
мы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ phpstorm64.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (phpstorm64.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Suggestion [3,General]: Команда phpstorm64.exe не найдена, однако существует в текущем расположении. По умолчанию оболочка Windows PowerShell не загружает команды из текущего расположения. Если вы уверены в надежности команды, введите ".\phpstorm64.exe". Для получения дополнительных сведений вызовите справку с помощью команды "get-help about_Command_Precedence".

Как мне открыть мой PHPStorm? Или не морочиться и переустановить? Хотя не факт, что заработает

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй его переустановить...

Comment: Так и вышло. Переустановил. Включилось. Вроде работает